# Ansible access variable in variable

Tags: ansible

I need to access a variable in a variable in a Ansible yml playbook.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{[hostvars['{{hostname}}']['ansible_facts']['os_family'] }}"
```

The variable is hostvars and i need my variable hostname (which contains the right value) to address the correct host, but ansible can't tranlate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have an `[` before `hostvars` and you don't need use `'{{ }}'` with `hostname` beacause `hostname` is a variable and it doesn't have to be between single quotes and you have already written `{{ }}` then you don't need write it again.

Try in this way

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{hostvars[hostname]['ansible_facts']['os_family'] }}"
```